# using Vector as Chart dataprovider?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

```
public class TMyClass 
{
   public var value : Number;
   public var scale : Number;
   public function TMyClass()
   {
   }

}

[Bindable]
public var myVector : Vector.<TMyClass> = new Vector.<TMyClass>();

yField="value" // the line series property
xFiled="scale"
```

I am trying to setup a **myVector** as dataprovider of a LineSeries in a Chart object.
everything going without issue on the build, but when i am executing it - there is an error that the property "value" doesn't exists.
If I switch the dataprovider to ArrayCollection - everything is going fine.

- Could Vector be used as dataprovider to a Chart series object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use the `Vector` class as the dataProvider. Even though `dataProvider` property is typed as `Object`, it has some expectations of what that object should be.

The setter method for the `dataProvider` property of a `LineSeries` (and assuming other chart series objects) is defined in the class `ChartElement`. If you look at that setter method, it eventually gets to a series of `if` statements where it checks the type of the `dataProvider` you've passed in. It checks to see if the `dataProvider` is one of the following types:

- `Array`
- `ArrayCollection`
- `XMLList`
- `XMLListCollection`
- `ListCollectionView`
- or anything that implements the `IList` or `ICollectionView` interfaces

If you want to use a `Vector`, you can wrap your `Vector` in class that implements `IList` or `ICollectionView`.

People have written classes that wrap a Vector and implement the `IList` interface, myself included. This allows you to use `Vector`'s with generally any Flex component that has a `dataProvider` property.

A design goal of my implementation was to avoid all the casting that other people's implementations were doing (never got around to doing any performance tests though).

- my own [VectorCollection](https://github.com/sunild/Flex-Collection-Utils) implementation
- [VectorCollection](http://www.digitalprimates.net/author/codeslinger/2010/05/18/vectorcollection/) from DigitalPrimates (I believe they have also contributed this implementation to the Apache Flex SDK (Flex 4.8)